# In Django (v1.6.5), what's the best practice for location of Templates, Static files?

Tags: django, templates, static

I am severely confused about where to put my templates files and static files.

I understand absolute and relative paths just fine, but I can't seem to find any instructions that mirror the installation I have. I know this resembles other questions, but those answers aren't working. The video I watched to successfully build a simple app didn't put templates in the Project folder, which is where logic tells me they should be.

**I have Python at:**
    
C:\Python27

**Django (v1.6.5) at:**
    
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django

**I created a project "mysite" and an app called "films."**

**Project "mysite":**
    
C:\Python27\Scripts\venv\mysite

**and an App "films":**
    
C:\Python27\Scripts\venv\mysite\films

The video I watched had me put my templates at:
    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates

But this seems completely stupid because the templates are outside of both the Project and the App.

1. Shouldn't I put a templates folder in the Project folder:
   C:\Python27\Scripts\venv\mysite\templates

And then create subdirectories using the App name?

1. What files do I need to edit (and how) to tell Django where to find them?
2. Follow a similar process for static files (css, images)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all frameworks, django offers great benefits if you follow some guidelines (and give up some control).  The trick is to know what these guidelines are.

For templates:

1. If the template is not tied to a particular application, put it in a `templates` directory at the root of your project. Add the full path to this directory to `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.
2. All other templates should go in a directory called `templates` inside your application directory. So if you application is called `myapp`, templates for `myapp` will go in `myapp/templates/`

For static files:

1. For files related to specific applications, inside your application directory create a directory called `static`, then inside it a directory with the name of your application. So, if your application is called `myapp`, you would have `myapp/static/myapp`. Place all your static content for this application here; for example `myapp/static/myapp/js/funky.js`.
2. For static files that are generic, create a directory called `assets` (or `static`) in the root directory of your project. Add the full path to this directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

By default, django will search all applications listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and add any `templates` and `static` directories to its search path for files. This is how, by default, the admin works without you having to configure anything.

If you chose to place your templates and static files in some other location, only then do you need to modify the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings.  If all your templates and static assets are tied to applications, just creating the directories as mentioned above makes everything work.

If you are wondering why you need to create another directory under `myapp/static/` to store your static files, this is more for portability.  The [`collectstatic` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) is a simply "copy and replace" utility.  It will overwrite all files in the `STATIC_DIR` location.  This means that if two applications have some static file with the same name, *they will be overwritten without warning*.  Adding a subdirectory keeps your application's static assets from being overwritten, because the exact path will be created.

Suppose you have two applications, `app1` and `app2`, and both have a file named `style.css` in their respected directories:

- `app1/static/css/style.css`
- `app2/static/css/style.css`

When you run `collectstatic`, you'll end up with the following (assuming `static` is the name of your `STATIC_DIR` setting):

- `static/css/style.css`

This may be the style.css from app1 or app2, the other cannot be determined (its actually based on the INSTALLED_APPS order).  To prevent this, if you have:

- `app1/static/app1/css/style.css`
- `app2/static/app2/css/style.css`

Now, you'll end up with:

- `static/app1/css/style.css`
- `static/app2/css/style.css`

Both files will be preserved.

You also shouldn't put your code in your virtual environment directory.  The virtual environment is not part of your source code, and placing your project in the same directory may cause problems later.

Create a single directory for your environments - I call mine `envs` (creative, I know). Create all your environments in this directory.  Once you activate the environment, you can work in any directory in your system and your shell will be configured for that environment's Python.

Finally for the best, accurate, most up-to-date information - always refer to the django manual and the tutorial. Almost all other resources (even the often suggested djangobook.com) are outdated.

Comment: I can't even figure out how to put carriage returns in this comment without this textarea losing focus and the form trying to save!!!

1. "So, if your application is called myapp, you would have myapp/static/myapp"

Why is it necessary to specify 'myapp' a second time in the path?

2. Concerning the virtual environment directory, there is nothing in this folder but Projects. In fact, I thought I was doing exactly what you're suggesting by putting putting them here! The /venv/ directory is a sibling object to django-admin.py, pip, virtualenv ...

Do you recommend I re-install differently?

Comment: The virtual environment (Python virtual environment), should not be the same directory where you have your django application.